# how to hide folder name from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain example.com i want to redirect it to example.com/public but /public folder should hide from the url.

I am using the below code in .htaccess to redirect, but unable to hide the folder name

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ public [L]
```

Please help me out for this issue.

Comment: A redirect or a _rewrite_?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public)
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+dirname/([^\s]+) [NC]// here you write your directory
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^dirname/)^(.*)$ /dirname/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Any it work :D but what to do when you have a subfolder? public/hello/world.php ?? if I write /hello/world I get a error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule (.*) public/$ [QSA,L]
```