# Omit folder name from browser URL via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using shared hosting, Linux, CPANEL, low-end account, no shell access.

I wish to have my website, `http://example.com`, located entirely inside a subfolder, like this:

```
/public_html/sub/example
```

At the moment, I am using the following `.htaccess` code to redirect visitors to this folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/mainsite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/mainsite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub/mainsite/index.php [L]
```

The problem is that the URI displayed in the address bar reflects this:

```
example.com/sub/mainsite/
```

I would like the address bar to look like this:

```
example.com

example.com/anotherpage   // <--- The .php extension removed
```

How can I do that using the `.htaccess`?

Do I need a second `.htaccess` file inside the `/sub/mainsite` folder? What would it say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323876/how-to-hide-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess

Comment: @m69 I had already seen that question and had been trying to make it work for me when I asked this question. Thanks for suggesting it, though, as it does seem somewhat related to what I need to do, but not closely enough that it helped to solve my particular problem.

Comment: Just curious, where does your .htaccess code originate? It's almost exactly the same as used in this _old_ question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983956/htaccess-rewrite-to-subdirectory