# jQuery AJAX submit form, url redirect or rewrite

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, url, submit

I have a php form and using the following function on this page: testsite.com/local-places

```
jQuery(".submit").click(function() {

             var dataString = jQuery("form#localsearch").serialize();

              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/index.php",
                data: dataString,
                  success : function( response ) {
                    alert( response );
                  }
              });
              return false;

        });
```

After submitting form, url looks like: testsite.com/local-places/?post_type=local&localtype=food-drink&category_name=northwest-austin

Is there a way to remove /local-places/ to end up with: testsite.com/?post_type=local&localtype=food-drink&category_name=northwest-austin

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're returning false, so the URL shouldn't change at all when you submit the form ?

Comment: return false so the page does not reload

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

You need to use an `.htaccess` file. This is a plain text file that begins with a dot and has the ending `htaccess` - no first part.

Try creating an `.htaccess` file containing only this (Untested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+local-places/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^local-places/)^(.*)$ /local-places/$1 [L,NC]
```

Source:

[how to hide folder name from url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323876/how-to-hide-folder-name-from-url-using-htaccess)